# Python3: Assign Concatenated String to a Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. I had a line of code to print strings along with variables. I decided to instead, assign what I had in the print statement to a variable, so I could print that information elsewhere. Once I assigned it to a variable it won't concatenate the string with the other variables.

`fin = 'Wins:' , str(wins) + '/' + runtime , '\nWin Percentage:' , str(winperc) + '%\n'`

Normally this would print out something like this:
**Wins: 308/1000
Win Percentage: 30.8%**

However when print that as a variable it comes out like this:
**('wins:', '311/1000', '\nWin Percentage:', '31.1%\n')**

I tried printing the variable as a string,but it did not work.
I can't think of anything else or find a solution for this. If you need to see the rest of the code I can paste it.

Comment: You're using Python 2.x in which `print` is a statement. -> `(..)` is interpreted as a tuple instead of function call. If you want to keep using Python 2.x, putting `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning of the file will solve the issue. https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html

Comment: Read about tuples: https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/#python-tuples

Comment: As @jarmod said, you have an issue related to tuples. As a hint: it's to do with your use of commas (`,`)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am using Python3. Sorry for the confusion, I didn't know what else to call print so I referred to it as a statement. I am new so didnt know better. :) I got the code to work though, ty

Answer (score 2):

```
fins = 'Wins: {}/{}, Win Percentage:{}%'.format(wins, runtime, winperc)
```

Use format() function.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, you can use this

```
print(f"Wins: {str(wins)}/{runtime} Win Percentage: {str(winperc)}%")
```

Simply, you just need to put your variable inside the `{}`

Answer (score -1):

String concatenation is always with `+`, not with comas. So it would be like this:

`fin = 'Wins:' + str(wins) + str(runtime) + '\nWin Percentage:' + str(winperc) + '%\n'`

Also make sure that you're running python 3. In python 2 the `print()` function is without parenthesis.

Comment: I am running Python3, there may have been confusion about that because I said "print statement" I just didn't know what else to call it.. anyway, in python3 i can concatenate strings and variables with a comma, I normally use + but when I tried it in this situation it was trying to add the variable (an integer) to the string, and giving me an error, so I used a comma.

Comment: You must use `str()` before concatenating an integrer, because strings only concatenate strings.